# Real time validation for input box using Primefaces/JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to know if there is a way to do real-time validation using Primefaces/JSF?

***My requirement looks simple:***

> **I've an input box which would take only unique name. For eg.., if an user is looking to input an name which already exists in database, it
>   should throw error message like "User Name already exists."  This
>   should happen as soon as the user has moved out of the input box**

Reference can be inferred from Google registration page

I've spent a lot of time researching on internet but haven't arrived at any concrete solution.

I'm primarily looking for a solution in **Primefaces/JSF**. Is it possible?

Comment: Question out of curiosity. In all your searches you did not encounter any hit on 'validators' (for the validation) or 'ajax' for the real-time realisation?

Comment: @Kukeltje Infact, I did encounter 'validator' and 'ajax' for real-time realisation, however since my requirement required me to fetch data from a list of items, was a bit curious to know as to how it could be accomplished in JSF/Primefaces

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with plain JSF. You just have to use a validator and add ajax behavior to your input field, e.g.

**facelet**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:messages id="messages" />
    <h:inputText value="#{anyBean.username}" validator="userValidator">
        <f:ajax render="@this messages" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

**validator**

```
@FacesConverter("userValidator")
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String username = (String) value;
        if (usernameExists(username)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("User Name already exists."));
        }
    }

    private boolean usernameExists(String username) {
        // check if username exists here
    }
}
```

Of course you can also use the equivalent PrimeFaces components p:messages, p:inputText and p:ajax.